# ZipZAP uncompressing ZIP file

Tags: cocoa, unzip, zipzap

I need to uncompress content of ZIP file into selected directory. I did make:

```
ZZArchive* archive = [ZZArchive archiveWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@:"blahblah.zip"]];
for (NSUInteger index = 0, count = archive.entries.count; index < count; ++index)
{
  ZZArchiveEntry* archiveEntry = archive.entries[index];
  NSString  *inZipFileName = nextEntry.fileName;
}
```

But how to uncompress archiveEntry into filename inZipFileName?

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it's simple:

```
NSData *data = [nextEntry data];
[data writeToFile:@"uncompressed_filename" atomically:NO];
```

Veni, vidi, vici...